# Find first number that is a palindrome in the first b bases of some list Racket

Tags: functional-programming, racket

> Find first number greater than `start`, which is a palindrome in minimum `b` bases from the list `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

I have function that converts a number in a list of digits in base b, and a function that checks if a list is palindrome. I don't get why my "`x`" is always 0.

```
(define (num->base n b)
  (if (= n 0) 
      '() 
      (append 
         (num->base (quotient n b) b) 
         (list (modulo n b)))))

(define (rev L)
  (if (null? L) '() (append (rev (cdr L)) (list (car L)))))

(define (palindrome? L)
  (equal? L (rev L)))

(define (first-b-pal start b)
  (define x 0)
  (for ([i '(2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)])
    (if (equal? (palindrome? (num->base start i)) #t)
        (+ x 1)
        (+ x 0)
    )
  )
  (display start)
  (display "\n")
  (display x)
  (display "\n")
  (if (> x (+ b 1))
        start
        (first-b-pal (+ start 1) b)
    )
  )
```

My idea was that, check for how many bases is start a palindrom, if that is greater than b then just return the number, otherwise call the function with start + 1, and I don't get why x is never incremented..

Comment: `+` does not increment anything, it just calculate a sum. So `(+ x 1)` does not increment `x`.

Comment: @Renzo then how should I approach it?

Comment: is `100` a palindrome? `00100` is and is a valid representation of `100`.. Btw you are doing this `x + 1`. In C# or JavaScript, does that increment `x` at all?

Comment: @Sylwester No, 100 is not a palindrome, no, but i dont know how to do ```x += 1``` in Racket.

Comment: What you're basically saying is that palindromes are odd numbers since an even number ends with a `0` and you never assume any of the inifnite zeroes in front of the first non zero digit to be part of it and thus not a palindrome in base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stays `0` since you never update the binding. You only use the value `0` as one of the arguments.

You update a binding with `set!` eg.

```
(set! x (+ x 1))
```

However it is not the idiomatic way. Here is an example. Imagine you want to sum all the elements of a list:

```
(define (sum lst)
  (define (helper acc lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (helper (+ acc (car lst))
                (cdr lst))))
  (helper 0 lst))

(sum '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 6
```

As you can see every iteration updates the `acc` and `lst` bindings, but while it works similar no mutation has happened.

Comment: Can you explain more what the binding is? What do you mean the binding? and why is the idiomatic way like this?

Comment: @C.Cristi It's a variable. It binds a name to an object. When you use use `set!` you alter what the variable binds to, as in redirect, to a different value **without** changing the actual objects. We also have `set-car!` that doesn't touch any bindings but alters the object in it's argument. Scheme was designed to be small and recursion it's only true control flow and since it's used in teaching keeping away from mutation makes functions easier to reason about. Eg. one can use the substitution method to understand what's happening.